# How to avoid mirroring canvas in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, 2d

I want to attach my healthbar and manabar to the player, but i cannot figure out how to attach it to a player winhout mirroring (the whole canvas flips everytime, when the player model flips).

Here is video: https://youtu.be/p9UvsMXUmLU

Here is the project: https://mega.nz/file/zUY0HYbL#ahwM_uGlp7-5iMLFjR1uaj6hgeVpjyhB3SCLe9xAt88

Answer (score 0):

In your CharacterController2D there is Flip() method which flips transform.localScale.x sign. Take a look at what this transform is. In your case your bars are children of a root object that you flipping. So it flips character_nomove.transform.x as well as all its children. You probably don't want to put those bars and its canvas under your character transform. I also don't see any reason for them to be in world space. Screen Space overlay is just enough here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to Un-Parent the bars and then use something like:

```
healthbar.transform.position = yourCharacter.transfomr.position + new vector2(0 , 1);
```

in an `Update` method to move it along the character and slightly above.
note that if your character is 2D sprite and the bars are in Canvas you've got to use something like:

```
healthbar.transform.position = Camera.Main.WorldToScreenPoint(yourCharacter.transfomr.position + new vector2(0 , 1));
```

to get the screen position(for Canvas) from your character placed in the world.